# Rails 4: `Time.now.utc.iso8601` sometimes off by 1 second in specs

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, utc, iso

I'm building a Rails 4 API with JSON, and am returning the `updated_at` attribute as UTC timezone in ISO format.

`record.updated_at # => 2015-04-14 10:01:37 -0400
record.updated_at.utc.iso8601 # => "2015-04-14T14:01:37Z"`

However, my `rspec` specs will occasionally fail intermittently when the `updated_at` is off by 1 second:

```
# records_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe RecordsController do
  describe "update - PUT #update" do
    record = FactoryGirl::create(:record, value: "original")
    record_params = { value: "updated" }

    xhr :put, api_v1_record_path(record), record_params

    # Uses ActiveModelSerializer
    # json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    expect(json["updated_at"]).to eq(record.updated_at.utc.iso8601)
  end
end

# app/serializers/record_serializer.rb
class RecordSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :value

  def created_at
    object.created_at.utc.iso8601
  end

  def updated_at
    object.updated_at.utc.iso8601
  end
end

# Running rspec...
Failure/Error: expect(json["updated_at"]).to eq(record.updated_at.utc.iso8601)

       expected: "2015-04-14T13:59:35Z"
            got: "2015-04-14T13:59:34Z"

       (compared using ==)
```

If I run the spec again, it passes many times, and then randomly it will fail again, with the time comparison being off by 1 second again.

Is there anyway to ensure consistent datetime conversions in the specs?

The biggest issue is that automated deploys with a CI server will randomly fail if the `rspec` suite randomly fails if a spec just happens to be on the fence of a given second.

Comment: Please provide the failing test code.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and it's very annoying.

Comment: @FCastellanos: The problem was I wasn't reloading the object, thus the "updated_at" timestamp was off.  See the solution I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was I wasn't reloading the object after the update actions, thus I was getting a "dirty" `updated_at`, and it failed sporadically because the tests happened so fast.

```
RSpec.describe RecordsController do
  describe "update - PUT #update" do
    record = FactoryGirl::create(:record, value: "original")              
    record_params = { value: "updated" }

    # record.updated_at => "2015-06-23 22:30:00"

    xhr :put, api_v1_record_path(record), record_params

    # record.updated_at => "2015-06-23 22:30:00"

    # SOLUTION CODE (notice timestamp updated below)
    record.reload

    # record.updated_at => "2015-06-23 22:30:01"


    # Uses ActiveModelSerializer
    # json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    expect(json["updated_at"]).to eq(record.updated_at.utc.iso8601)
  end
end
```

I found that for any of my specs that altered/updated a record, I would have to reload the object to get the proper timestamps values.  I don't have better general approach than that.

If someone has a cleaner solution, feel free to post it and I'll accept it over mine.

Comment: You could freeze time with `ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers` (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html) or Timecop (https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop).